# PHP Session variable lost after .htaccess url rewrite

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, session-variables, php

The problem that I have is that one of the session variables does not get saved while navigation between pages, but it does get saved when I try to access the page directly via php file.
Example:

When I access the page this way:
"http://www.domain.com/products/honey-4-dozes"
and then navigate away from it this is what the content of $_SESSION array is:

```
Array
(
    [curr_sku] => honey4doz
    [username] => testuser
    [firstname] => John
    [lastname] => Doe
)
```

But when I access the page directly this way:
"http://www.domain.com/product.php?product=honey-4-dozes"
and then navigate away from it this is what the content of $_SESSION array is:

```
Array
(
    [curr_sku] => 
    [username] => testuser
    [firstname] => John
    [lastname] => Doe
)
```

I'm also checking for any changes in session id but the ID does not change thru the whole process. Infact username, firstname and lastname fields which get created on different page get passed between the pages just fine. Any ideas why this might be happening?

$_SESSION['curr_sku'] variable is created on product.php page.

This is the rewrite rule I use:
**RewriteRule ^products/(.*+)$ product.php?product=$1 [QSA]**

Also this is the content of session cookie parameters which I get with session_get_cookie_params():

```
{
    [lifetime] => 0
    [path] => /
    [domain] => 
    [secure] => 
    [httponly] => 
)
```

Part of the code that sets the variable:

```
$result = mysqli_query($link,"SELECT * FROM products WHERE url = '$curr_product'");
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result); 
$_SESSION['curr_sku']=$row['sku'];
```

Comment: show the code that sets the session varariable

Comment: The problem exists in the PHP code, as this rewrite does nothing affecting the session variable

Comment: Above I have just added the part of code that sets the variable.

Comment: Also if this is a PHP problem how come this only occurs when I access the page thru rewritten URL and not when i access it directly?

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

For http://www.domain.com/products/honey-4-dozes

```
RewriteRule ^products/(.*+)$ product.php?product=$1 [QSA]
```

And  for http://www.domain.com/products/product=honey-4-dozes

```
RewriteRule ^products/product=(.*+)$ product.php?product=$1 [QSA]
```

I hope, I could help.